# What is the most fundamental reason for introduction of force moment $\vec{M}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque, moment

Force moment is defined as $\vec{M}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$ when force is perpendicular to the lever arm.

How do we know that it has to be this way? How do we know it is not $F\cdot r^2$ etc. ?

My reasoning is sth like things don't rotate when the force is applied through the CM/axis of rotation of an object. So the new physical quantity has to know to be zero then. However it doesn't explain why multiply by $r^1$, $r^3$ is gonna work well in this case.

I might be looking for a historical explanation, don't know precisely what I am looking for. Something bugs me there.  Happy to hear your thoughts in general!

Comment: related: [Why is torque defined as $\vec r\times \vec F$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705214/)